# How to Use RTC Module (DS1302) to specifically Execute a Program at a Certain Time

Tags: usb, usb-power, rtc, ds1307

I had already completed a Setup of DS1302 on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ and fortunately its working just fine.

I also already solved the Problem of Turning On and Off the USB Port using "uhubctl".

https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl

The Problem was How can I use my RTC Module (DS1302) to Turn On and Off at Specific Time.

Comment: (1( Well one stupid way is ask the Rpi to check the RTC every second, and execute a specific program at a specific time.  (2) For smarter RTC, such as DS3231, you can program the RTC to interrupt Rpi when the time comes. Ref: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135258/can-i-turn-on-and-off-my-raspberry-pi-3b-on-a-specific-time

Comment: turn what on and off at a specified time?

Comment: USB Port specifically

Comment: What is the purpose of turning the usb port on/off at a specific time?

Comment: I'd like to turn off my at least my Arduino to save power as I am using Solar Panel in my Project. I figured it was good. since all my sensors are connected to Arduino.

Comment: If the RTC is correctly setup there is NO NEED to do anything. It sets system clock - just use cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to synchronize the clock of the Pi with your RTC and simply use `cron`. Depending on how much your pi diverges, you can sync the clock of the pi from time to time in `cron` too.

Typically, that would look like :

```
#M   H  dom mon dow cmd
 0   *   *   *   *  rtc-pi
 0  12   *   *   *  script_to_turn_on
 5  12   *   *   *  script_to_turn_off
```

--- addition---

For those that have a DS1302, it may be obvious that `rtc-pi`  is the program that interfaces with the DS1302 module. It is not in the standard repositories, but can be obtained from (among others) `https://zedt.eu/storage/2014/07/rtc-pi-20140727.zip`. For other versions of the RTC (like the DS1307) the command would be `hwclock`, which can be downloaded from `https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/pi-hats.git`

Comment: Thanks. Already did that. It works just fine. Many Thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm a little intoxicated also, but this answer does not seem to address the question, stated obtusely as, "How can I use my RTC Module (DS1302) to Turn On and Off at Specific Time." Blinking my way through the alcoholic fog, I can only assume that the OP was referring to the `uhubctl` to turn his USB ports on & off. IoW, this answer has nothing to do with the RTC. Of course, the OP did accept this answer, but can you explain what the command `rtc-pi` is?

Comment: rtc-pi is the program that interfaces with the DS1302. Basically, you can set an initial time on the clock module and set the time on the pi from the clock module.

Comment: And so `rtc-pi` is not an actual program that's available from anywhere? ... `apt-cache search rtc-pi` doesn't show anything by that name.  BTW, You get a notification when anyone posts a comment here because this is your answer. But if you reply to a comment here, you must add their *handle* for them to get a notification; e.g. @seamus in my case.

Comment: @Seamus: didn't know about the need for the handle. Sorry about that. I added some comment about interfacing with the RTC modules.